# Why my firebug is not showing all javascript error

Tags: windows, firefox, google-chrome, firebug

I clearly remember that 2 months ago whenever i had any javascript error , It was shown as red text in Firefox console , and i knew what is the problem.

But now its not doing that.

I had one undefined variable and i was using that. But i didn't knew. i had to waste 1 hour to find that.

But firebug didn't show anything on console. It was showing before 2-3 months back

Same in Firefox and Google chrome

What should i do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try firebug 1.2b12 from http://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug.
Please check that you have Console enabled and Console > Options >
Javascript Errors checked.

If you still have a problem please open a bug report and attach a
complete test case.

Source : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/firebug/HgpEGNLZ18c

Comment: thanks , 1.2b was compatible with current version of firefox , so i installed the latest one and its working fine